# Can anyone recommend disk I/O benchmarking software for Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, benchmarking, hard-drive, disk-io

I want to test the performance of a filesystem under different conditions.

Specifically I want to test the performance of Windows virtual machines without compression and with compression both on "normal harddisk" and on USB-disk as it would be interesting to see exactly what the difference is.

**What I need is a program that can test different aspects of filesystem (random access, sequential read/write, etc)** and make pretty graphs that go well with my blog. Preferrably the application should be automated so I can add it to startup, this way the timing is the same for each run and I can repeat the runs for verification.

I can post a link to the results here when I get around to testing it. Right now its just in the planning phase.

Comment: Compression will be noticeably slower. Skip the tests, unless you really like graphs and pretty pictures.

Comment: @Cody Gray this is not exactly true and depends on the disk type and filesystem itself.

Comment: @Eugene: Yeah, a compressed file on an SSD will be faster than a compressed file on a floppy disk. But all else being equal, the overhead of *decompression* will cause that file system to be slower every time.

Comment: @Cody what *else being equal* are you talking about? My point is that the difference ratio (between compressed and uncompressed) on SSD will be different from the ratio on shared network drive.

Comment: I don't agree - mem/cpu-time is considerably lower than disk time so for a defragmented disk I'd expect compression to speed things up. I'm interested in seeing the actual difference. One of the biggest bottlenecks on a (low-end) server with 2-3 virtual machines is the disk.

Comment: Here is a tool written in java. It has graphs! https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdiskmark/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Iometer](http://www.iometer.org/) is *the* I/O measurement tool. And it's free. From the website:

> Iometer is an I/O subsystem
>   measurement and characterization tool
>   for single and clustered systems. It
>   was originally developed by the Intel
>   Corporation and announced at the Intel
>   Developers Forum (IDF) on February 17,
>   1998 - since then it got wide spread
>   within the industry.
>
> Meanwhile Intel has discontinued to
>   work on Iometer and it was given to
>   the Open Source Development Lab
>   (OSDL). In November 2001, a project
>   was registered at SourceForge.net and
>   an initial drop was provided. Since
>   the relaunch in February 2003, the
>   project is driven by an international
>   group of individuals who are
>   continuesly improving, porting and
>   extend the product.
>
> The tool (Iometer and Dynamo
>   executable) is distributed under the
>   terms of the Intel Open Source
>   License. The iomtr_kstat kernel module
>   as well as other future independent
>   components are distributed under the
>   terms of the GNU Public License.

Comment: I'm not too impressed by the supported platforms, windows up to XP and no support for mac. Is there an updated support matrix other than: http://www.iometer.org/doc/matrix.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Additional server oriented disk benchmarks:

- [Diskspd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223)
- [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio/)
- [vdbench](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vdbench-downloads-1901681.html)

Answer (score 0):

You said you'd like pretty graphs for your blog. In my use of [IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/), I've never seen it produce a graph. However, it is possible that I overlooked an existing feature.

Alternatively, (from the look of its website) [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) might give you graphs:
http://www.iozone.org/

Yet, it could be that iozone only **collected the data used** to create those graphs shown on its web site.

Regardless, this is still another option for I/O Benchmarking.